# Intent content is not being parsed to intentservice

Tags: android, android-intent, action, intentservice

I'm having trouble passing an intent with an action to an intentservice. The service can be launched and the intent isn't null but the action is null. The same problem occurs when putExtra is being used.

When I reach the first breakpoint I can see that the action has been filled in but when I reach the breakpoint in the onHandleIntent method my action is empty. 
The action is also already empty in the onStart method and in the onStartCommand method.

I have included the code for my intentservice class. I use the method getNewDeck as a helper method so that I'm able to call this method from various activities without needing to create an intent or perhaps forgetting certain parameters. This helper method starts the service. But I've already started the service from an activity and the problem persists so I don't think the problem lays there.

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

public static final String TAG="MyService";
public static final String MY_SERVICE_MESSAGE="myServiceMessage";
public static final String MY_SERVICE_PAYLOAD="myServicePayload";


private static final String SR_GET_NEW_DECK="getNewDeck";
private static final String SR_DRAW_CARDS_FROM_DECK="drawCardsFromDeck";

private static final String PARAM_DECK_ID="deckID";

private static final String PARAM_DRAW_CARDS_FROM_DECK_COUNT="count";



private DeckApiService deckApiService;
/**
 * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
 */
public MyService() {
    super("MyService");
}



public static void getNewDeck(Context context) {
    Intent i=new Intent(context,MyService.class);
    i=i.setAction(SR_GET_NEW_DECK);
    context.startService(i); //breakpoint (action is "getNewDeck" here.)
}




@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Intent messageIntent=null;

    deckApiService=DeckApiService.retrofit.create(DeckApiService.class);


    if (intent != null) {

        final String action = intent.getAction(); // breakpoint (intent.getAction() is null here)

        try {
            switch (action) {
                case SR_GET_NEW_DECK:
                    //Geeft een nieuw deck terug, het deckid is op te vragen
                    messageIntent = handleGetNewDeck();
                    break;

                case SR_DRAW_CARDS_FROM_DECK:
                    //Geeft een pile terug met getrokken kaarten uit een deck
                    //in de intent zijn deckID en het aantal te trekken kaarten meegegeven
                    messageIntent = handleDrawCardsFromDeck(intent);
                    break;

                default:
                    Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent: Wrong parameters");
                    messageIntent = null;
                    break;

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent: Wrong intent");
            messageIntent = null;
        }
    }


    if(messageIntent!=null) {
        LocalBroadcastManager manager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        manager.sendBroadcast(messageIntent);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't created in this section of code, I started the intentservice in another method with an empty intent. The intent that was created in the code above was used after the first call had finished.